# Windows Pandoc TexLive

Tags: texlive, windows, pandoc

I installed the latest texlive and pandoc on windows 8.

I am able to compile tex to pdfs by manually invoking pdflatex.

When I try to go from markdown to pdf via pandoc I get an error about not being able to find article.cls

I don't have a user name over 8 characters.

If I uninstall TexLive and switch to MikTex it works.

I tried to get support from the official pandoc channels but after looking at paths, usernames, etc.. it was suggest I post something here.

We are trying to figure out why running pdflatex from the command line would work but running from pandoc would not.

Comment: This is now fixed in the most recent versions of Pandoc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because according to the comments this has been fixed in pandoc.